# Is TideSDK Production ready?

Tags: web-applications, air, tidesdk, tidekit

I am planning to develop an standalone app that will run on OSX and Windows using Html5, etc. I have been doing some analysis on some of the frameworks that will suite my needs.

This is one of the blog that I came across.

http://blog.neamlabs.com/post/36584972328/2012-11-26-web-app-cross-platform-desktop-distribution

This blog is an old one and I felt like tideSDK is promising, So I  would like to know whether tideSDK is production ready? Or do we have any other options like tideSDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TideSDK is still in beta, therefore it does not exactly provide what you are looking for.

We are currently working on something new, it is called TideKit.

TideKit is a platform you can use to create native apps for web, desktop and mobile from a single code base written in JavaScript. It also provides code hiding and everything you need to create a world-class native app for multiple devices, not only desktop.

If you are interested in TideKit, follow us @TideKit on Twitter or watch our short video on YouTube
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aE7gN-d0GhU

Comment: As of now, I have few deadlines to meet.So, If I go ahead with tideSDK in MAC, then I can reuse source code to build the .exe in windows rite?. At this point of time I am not worried about the deploying completely. I need to pass the .app and .exe files to my client so that they can use this app in their local machine to communicate with another app that we have already developed and deployed. Please correct me If I said something wrong, As I have been  not used to tideSDK.

Comment: Yes, using TideSDK you should be able to reuse your source code across Windows, osx and ubuntu.